# What is the difference between these two cases of adding a string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I noticed that when I initialized a string, the compiler reported an error that I was not expecting.

***For example:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1 = "Hello", s2 = "World!"; // ok
    string s3 = s1 + ", " + "World!"; // ok
    string s4 = "Hello" + ", " + s2; // error
    cout << s1 + " " + s2 << endl; //ok
    return 0;
}
```

For me, if `s3` worked just fine, `s4` should do the same.

**Why do I get that error?  What is the difference between these two initialization strings (`s3` and `s4`)?**

Comment: This is just a little inconvenience of C++. You can use `std::string() + "Hello" + ...` to make it compile without significant penalty.

Comment: If you're coming from another language background, you will be shocked to learn that `"Hello"` is not a `string`. And that's the cause of all (not only) your trouble.

Comment: @NeilKirk that is kind of weird, but thank you for the information. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Walter now you really got my attention. Can you talk more about that?

Comment: Well it is a "string", it depends what you mean by "string". It is a C-style string stored in an array of chars, `const char[6]`. But it is not a `std::string`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @NeilKirk , you and Walter helped me a lot.

Comment: To concatenate two string literals, just write them next to each other. `string s4 = "Hello" ", " + s2;`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and also for the edited post @T.C. !

Comment: An additional quirk is that `string s4 = "Hello"    ", " + s2;` **without** the first `+` works, because the preprocessor will concatenate adjacent string literals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`"Hello"` is not a `std::string` (rather it is a `const char[6]`, while `", "` is a `const char[3]`) and the `+` operator for `std::string`s does not apply.

This is a minor inconvenience of C++ and stems from its C ancestry. It means that in concatenating strings via `+` you must ensure that at least one of its *two* operands actually is a `std::string`, as in

```
auto s = std::string{"Hello"} + ", " + "World";
```

where the first `+` has a `std::string` as its first operand and hence produces a `std::string`, so that the second `+` also has a `std::string` as its first operand (since `+` is processed from left to right).

---

**Edit1** prompted by the comment by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c), I mention that C-string literals are automatically concatenated if only separated by white space:

```
std::string s = "Hello" ", " "World";
```

This behaviour too is inherited from C: the preprocessor renders above code to

```
std::string s = "Hello, World";
```

before the compiler proper processes it (to be more precise, string concatenation takes place in [phase 6](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) of translation, just before compilation). This is in fact the most simple and hence most convenient way to concatenate raw string literals. But note that I had to declare the type of `s`, since `auto` deduction would have given a `const char*`.

---

**Edit2** prompted by the comment by [PaperBirdMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499359/paperbirdmaster), I mention that since C++14, you can directly form `std::string` literals by simply adding `s` after the string, *if* you pull in the associated [`operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (or surrounding namespace).

```
using std::literals::operator""s;                // pull in required operator
const auto s = "Hello"s + ", " + "World";        // std::string
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556504/why-is-operators-hidden-in-a-namespace) as to why the required `operator""s` is hidden in the nested namespace. Note also that alternatively to `using std::literals::operator""s;` you may pull in the surrounding `namespace`: either of the following declarations will do.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
using namespace std::literals;
```

which are not as bad (and damned) as plain `using namespace std;`.

Comment: That explains a lot, in a very clear and fast way. Thank you for that, @Walter !

Comment: Or, you know, drop the `+` and let string literal concatenation work its magic :)

Comment: I think that is worth to mention the use of UDL, the following is valid: `string s4 = "Hello"s + ", " + s2;` as long as we are `using namespace std::string_literals;` (C++14 only)

Comment: @bku_drytt My answer is/was correct, though for the unaware this may not be obvious. The point is that the `operator+` has exactly 2 arguments, at least one of which must be a `std::string`. I clarified the answer as to what operand means in the example code.

Comment: As for concatenating raw string literals, is done in "Phase 6" of translation, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) we have all the phases explained.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Yes, phase 6 is still preprocessing in the broader sense (than just phase 4). I added a remark in brackets.

Answer (score 6):

## Strings and C-strings

In C++, strings are usually represented as either [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or a [C-string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) which has type `char[N]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the C-string plus one for the termination character (or null character) `\0`.

When passing a string literal as, *e.g.*, `"Hello"` to a function, you are actually passing a `char[6]`, which will *decay* into a pointer `char*`, as C++ does not allow you to pass arrays by value. Additionally, C++ does *not* allow non-const pointers to string literals, and the parameter type must therefore become `const char*`.

#### Concatenation

`std::string` has existing overloads for the [binary addition operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) which allows you to concatenate two `std::string` objects into one, as well as concatenate a `std::string` object with a C-string.

```
std::string s1 = "Hello";
std::string s2 = "World";

// Uses 'std::string operator+(const std::string&, const std::string&)'.
std::string s3 = s1 + s2;

// Uses 'std::string operator+(const std::string&, const char*)'.
std::string s4 = s1 + "World";

// Also ok.
std::string s4 = "Hello" + s2;
```

There is however, no overload for concatenating two C-strings.

```
// Error. No overload for 'std::string operator+(const char*, const char*)' found.
std::string s5 = "Hello" + "World";
```

#### From left to right

Addition is performed [left to right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in C++, and hence, long concatenation expressions need to start with a `std::string` object.

```
std::string s6 = "Hello" + ", " + s2; // Error. Addition is performed left-to-right and
                                      // you can't concatenate two C-strings.

std::string s7 = s1 + ", " + "World"; // Ok. 's1 + ", "' returns a new temporary
                                      // 'std::string' object that "World" is concat'ed to.
```

## A simple solution

Using C++14 *standard literals*, you can create `std::string` objects from literal expressions (note the trailing `s` in the literal expression).

```
using namespace std::literals;
std::string s8 = "Hello"s + ", " + "World"; // Ok
```

Alternatively you can use the fact that the preprocessor will automatically concatenate literal strings separated with *whitespace*.

```
std::string s9 = "Hello" ", " "World"; // Ok
```

But then, you could just as well skip the whitespace altogether and use a single string literal.

Comment: Thank you @Snps for you contribution, it is always good to know more about C++14 !

Answer (score 5):

The following line attempts to add 2 pointers together.

```
string s4 = "Hello" + ", " + s2; // error
```

`"Hello"` is a `const char[6]` which decays to `const char*` and `", "` is a const `char[3]` which decays to `const char*`.

You are trying to assign the addition of two pointers to a `std::string`, which is not valid. Furthermore, the addition of two pointers is not valid either.

As other people have said, this doesn't have anything to do with the overloads of `operator+` of the `std::string` class, as the following code would also not compile for the same reason:

```
string s4 = "Hello" + ", ";
```

I have added some clarifications provided by user **@dyp**.

You can fix your problem by using the C++ Standard Library "user-defined" string literal. The functionality is provided by `std::literals::string_literals::operator""s` which is found in the `<string>` header. You might have to use a using-directive or -declaration; this was not required on my compiler and including the `<string>` header was enough. Example:

```
string s4 = "Hello"s + ", "s + s2;
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
string s4 = std::string("Hello") + std::string(", ") + s2;
```

When you place an instance of `std::string` as the first operand, the rest of the expression will use that type, because of left to right associativity for operator+ will make sure that an instance of `std::string` is returned as the left-most operand every time, instead of `const char*`. That is why you have no error on line:

```
string s3 = s1 + ", " + "World!";
```

That line is equivalent to:

```
string s3 = ((s1 + ", ") + "World!");
```

Comment: Thank you for that @bku_drytt , now your answer is clear for me!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated my answer to include your knowledge.

Comment: Both `std::literals` and `std::literals::string_literals` are *inline namespaces*, so a using-directive `using namespace std;` is sufficient to make this `operator""s` visible.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to understand is that due to its ancestry in C, a string literal like `"Hello"` in C++ is *not* actually of type `string`. Its type is actually an array of characters instead.

So the difference between `s3` and `s4` is that when you do the `s3` construction, the first operation done is `s1 + ", "`. `s1` is of type string, so the `+` operator provided by the string component of the standard library is used, and returns a new string to be added to `"World!"`.

Now for `s4` the first operation to be performed is `"Hello" + ", "` or the addition of two string literals. This operation would actually been see to the compiler as adding two character arrays together, a capability not provided by the language, thus resulting in the error you see.

The simplest fix is to just not use `+` for string literals, just put them all together in the same string. Alternately you could create a `string` from the first literal and let the operation work from there (`std::string("Hello") + ", " + s2`)

Answer (score 2):

The + operator is overloaded in std::string.
Operator overloads are applied to the operands, so
`s1 + ...` works by calling the overloaded + operator on s1.

Literal `"Hello"` is a `const char *` and so is `","`. `const char *` does not have an overloaded + operator, hence the error.
Try `string("Hello") + ...` and it will work.

Thanks for the correction @interjay

Comment: Operator overloads are not applied only to the left operand. There is also a `const char * + std::string` overload. The problem here is attempting to add two `const char *`.

Comment: What @interjay said. `string s4 = "Hello" + s2;` would also work.

Comment: `"Hello"` is not a `const char *`. It's a `const char[6]`, which can decay to `const char *`.