# Is there a way to use operator+ to concatenate std::strings in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a function like this

```
void foo (const char* myString){
...
}
```

and I want to use it like this

```
std::string tail = "something";
foo("my" + "string" + tail);
```

But I just can't find an easy way. For sure I can make the string somewhere else and pass it to `foo()`. But I prefer to find a way to do it inline, because `foo()` is called several times in the code, I don't want to make a string for each time. I tried

```
foo(std::string ("my" + "string" + tail).c_str())
```

but you can guess that it doesn't work.

Comment: What if you use `tail.c_str()`?

Comment: Why not use strcat()?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555142/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-cases-of-adding-a-string/32555209#32555209

Comment: @KaneAnderson: Because you have to allocate memory explicitly before you can use `strcat`.

Comment: In C++14 you can write `"my"s + "string" + tail`

Comment: String literals are automatically concatenated during compilation. Just remove the `+`.

Comment: @M.M: And from my tests on this earlier, using C++14 string literals is almost always better than allowing C-style string literals to auto-promote. At least on `g++` 5.1 for Linux x64, the auto-promotion involves explicit runtime length calculations on the C-style string literal with code to handle errors related to the check, where using the C++14 literal syntax determines the necessary information at compile time, so construction boils down to fixed length allocation and `memcpy` and a hundred bytes or so fewer instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"my"`and `"string"` are C style string literals, which have the odd rule that they will be concatenated if they are written **without** a `+`.

So `"my" "string" + tail` will work, and produce a `std::string`. However, it will still not be the correct type for your function, unless you use `.c_str()` on the result.

Comment: @Sasan: Your edit changes the entire nature of the question. That's a good example of why Stackoverflow prefers compilable example code.

Comment: @Cristian Hackl, I see! This was my first post on Stackoverflow, I'll do a better job next time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure "my" is a `std::string`, then you can use the `std::string::operator+` operator on it. Later you use `.c_str()` on the resulting `std::string`.

Then, if you can change `foo`, the best is to make it accept `const char*`:

```
void foo (const char* myString)
{
    ...
}

std::string tail = "something";
foo( (std::string("my") + "string" + tail).c_str() );
```

If you can't change `foo`, then you'll have to do a cast because `c_str()` returns a `const char*` and `foo` wants a `char*`:

```
void foo (char* myString)
{
    ...
}

std::string tail = "something";
foo( const_cast<char*>( (std::string("my") + "string" + tail).c_str() ) );
```

Comment: Downvoting for const_cast.

Comment: @SergeyA: Thank you for saying why you downvote, it's so rare....And I'd like to know what would be better! Please. Because you definitely have to do something about it if you cannot change `foo` declaration.

Comment: @jpo38: Allocate a `char*` yourself and copy the contents from the `std::string`. Or use a `std::vector<char>` to avoid the manual `char*` handling.

Comment: Thanks @jpo38. Your suggestion works, and as SergeyA pointed out, it doesn't need the const_cast.

Comment: Upvoting for accurately explaining the options.

Comment: @Sasan: As the code stands, it should not compile without the `const_cast`. There might be a problem with your compiler settings.

Comment: I wish i could upvote you all! haha, it doesn't let me yet!

Answer (score 1):

`"my"` and `"string"` are C-style strings. Their types are `const char *`, you cannot use `operator +` for these operands. But you can use this operator is any of the operands is `string`.

So the most elegant way for you it to add parenthesis:

```
foo(("my" + ("string" + tail)).c_str());
```

You will also have to change function `foo` to

```
void foo (const char* myString)
```

Comment: This does not work: `error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void foo(char*)'`

Comment: Ah I missed the type of function argument

Answer (score 1):

Your function accepts a modifiable array (not anymore, OP changed that in an edit) of `char` and `std::string` is *not* an array of `char`, but some unrelated object (that provides *read*-access to its internal `char` buffer, but that does not make it some kind of pretty array).

Additionally, using `.c_str()`-pointers into destroyed string objects is a common bug. Even if your function was to accept a `const char*` instead, you need to be aware that the pointer passed into it would only be valid until the end of the full expression the temporary `std::string` object was created in. This might or might not be what you want here, but is something you really need to watch out for. As I said, people get it wrong quite often.

So `std::string` probably (in the new `const char*` setting, it might) is not the right tool for this job as it is described right now.
The best solution would be to make the argument of `foo()` an `std::string` (of some reference variant, depending on what it is doing). Then you can concatenate the inputs with `+` as long as one of the first summands already is an `std::string`.

If this should not be possible, copy the characters into an `std::vector<char>` which actually is the C++ way to get a `char` array (again, unlike `string`).

Comment: Baum is correct, but I edited I already corrected my question. My function expects `const char*`.

Comment: @Sasan Which then invalidated every upvoted answer at that time. That is at least bad style IMO. The answer still stands correct as is.

Answer (score 0):

The code `foo("my" + "string" + tail);` does not work for two reasons. First is order of operators. The code tries to execute "my" + "string", and since both of those are string literals, code fails. (you can not add up two string literals). The first issue is that if you magically make "my" + "string" working, code will concatenate it with tail, produce valid std::string, but fail to pass it to foo().

How to fix the issue?

1. Change foo() signature. make it `foo(const char* )` if you have to use char*, or, better, replace it with `foo(const std::string&)`.
2. Use following to concatenate: `foo(std::string("my") + "string" + tail)` if you followed my advice and made foo accepting const std::string&, or `foo((std::string("my") + "string" + tail).c_str())` if you did not.
3. On a side note, since both "my" and "string" are known at compile time, it's better to have simple foo("mystring" + tail) - easier to read, better performance.